# TemplateDoesNotExist: home.html, femat/law_list.html

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Why I am getting the above error while I have not defined or requested "law_list.html"? Where does the law_list.html come from? It should be something wrong with model and class based view. I am using Django 3.1.3.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models


class Law(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    E = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.E)



#views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Law


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Law
    template_name = 'home.html'

#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomeView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

Comment: Show us the entire error traceback massage, not just the final line.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
template_name= "femat/home.html"
```

Comment: Yes, it renders properly now. Thank you. Still I cannot understands the the second part of the error message.

Comment: Law_list.html is the default html that ListView will look for, derived from your model name. See docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/